# Live stream in iOS with Wowza media server

Tags: ios, iphone, streaming, wowza, wowza-transcoder

I am facing issue to live stream video using Wowza server in iOS but in Android, working perfect with RTPS?

I have follow this certain step for live stream with RTMPStreamPublisher:

1. Use [MediaLib class](https://github.com/slavavdovichenko/MediaLibDemos) for connection b/w wowza server & iOS App through RTMPStreamPublisher.
2. Connection Success b/w iOS App and Wowza server.
3. Showing streaming in Wowza "Adobe RTMP" & "Adobe HDS" Test Player
   but not on "Apple HLS" player.
4. Stream "1 KB" file create in wowza stream directory but stream not saving.

I am not getting, why stream not save and not playback on "Apple HLS", its any wowza setting issue or other?

Please suggest the way to live stream.

Have a Great Day a head!

Answer (score -1):

Add stream name like this ::

```
flv:stream name
```

save your video in `flv` format
...